# Use Rails 4 engine in Rails 3.2 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

Is it possible to create a rails engine and insert it into a 3.2.14 application? I want to put a blogging engine into an older Rails app. Will the gemfiles collide or stand on their own?

Answer (score 1):

Rails Engines can be used in 3.2.x applications.  But the Engine gem dependencies must allow use of Rails 3.2.x.  If the engine's dependencies strictly require Rails 4 then you will not be able to use the engine with your Rails 3.2 app.

Comment: How to loosen the gem's dependency on rails? Usually in rails engine, the rails version is specified in its gemspec file.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use two versions of Rails at once, but if your engine is 3.2 compatible, then you might have luck. Or, you can use an older version of that engine that is compatible, perhaps?